# How offensive is the French word "femmelette" considered to be?

Tags: usage

How offensive is the French word "femmelette" considered to be? I know it's used to describe a weak or overly sensitive male, so I assume it's mostly used to offend males, but is it considered to be offensive to females, too?

I know it technically translates to "a weak woman," so would it be considered kind of stupid for a female to use that word? Is it like an equivalent to the English word "pussy"? I hear females use that word to describe males or females all of the time, and I've never heard anyone say it was stupid for a female to say that even though it's a word that's generally referred to females.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

It’s vulgar, and yes the english word to translate it could be « pussy »

Per the description; it’s tagged for a men acting like a women

> Fig. Homme qui a des manières féminines. C'est une vraie > femmelette, comment supportera-t-il les fatigues de la > guerre s'il est appelé à l'armée ?

In Canadian French it’s not much used. « Feluette » is more used or even « tapette » which is more vulgar.

- Feluette is a derivate word from [fluet](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fluet_fluette/34263).

The [urban dictionnary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=feluette) description:

> feluette similar to "moumoune", meaning wuss or weakling. Force un
>   peu, maudite feluette!

- tapette is more vulgar, as the primary meaning is a vulgar word that mean a homosexual, but it can be used to taunt someone else like feluette or femmelette.

In a conversation these words can be used for taunting (« narguer »), so the usage meaning can vary on the situation, but it’s still vulgar in any case.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the exact meanings and usages of the other words you mentioned, "feluette," "tapette," and "narguer"? Would it be completely weird for someone speaking French, not Canadian French, to use them?

Comment: @user8611261 Yes I will edit, for narguer it's more the act to tell femmelette, I didn't found the correct english word to translate it, it kinda mean "taunt"

Comment: From the perspective of a European French native speaker: *tapette* and *femmelette* are also very common here, but not "feluette". You can also find a less offensive word *chochotte* (not sure if it is used in Canadian French).

Comment: @Greg What's the exact definition/usage of "chochotte"?

Comment: *Chochotte* qualifies someone (more often a boy, even small children) who acts effeminate and avoids or refuses to do certain "manly" things. It is often used with the phrase *faire sa chochotte* (=to act like a sissy). Ex: "arrête de faire ta chochotte et viens te baigner, l'eau n'est pas trop froide !" I'd rate it as less offensive than *femmelette*.

Comment: It's not “men acting like a women”, it's meant acting like **a stereotypical woman who is weak because she's a woman**. It's inherently sexist against women.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's **vulgar**. It's **informal**, but it's not a curse word. If you're in elementary school and your teacher hears you say "femmelette", you're not particularly in trouble (as opposed to "merde" or "putain" for instance)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat There are not many schools you'd be in trouble for saying *merde* and not many in the south of France for saying  *putain*. But nowadays when teachers are asked to be particularly careful about all sexist discrimination *femelette* would never go unnoticed, an if it did then the teacher would be the one who could get in trouble.

Comment: @Gilles It's sexist, but it mean **effiminé** too, which mean something beyond the fact that a women can be weak.

Comment: @Gilles I personally would disagree on the meaning. In my opinion "-lette" just means small/weak in general. It's like saying "jupette" or "cigarette" is a small/short jupe or cigar **because** it's a jupe/cigar.

Comment: @Pepper No, it's different. If *femmelette* was applied to women, it would be the same. But *femmelette* is mostly applied to men.

Comment: It's applied to men in the sense "men should be ashamed of acting like women", so of course it doesn't make sense to apply it to women. While I agree that one could assume what you meant, it's subjective, in my opinion

Comment: I would argue that a word like "pussy", because it can applied to women, is inherently sexist since it associates negative characteristics directly to the gender itself (cowardice for example) that even other women should be ashamed of.

Comment: Je ne partage pas ton avis sur l'emploi au Canada mais j'imagine que c'est une question de quelle région on habite et d'âge etc. Dans mon expérience, _femmelette_ est bien plus courant que _feluette_, que je n'ai jamais employé de ma vie même si je connais le mot. _Moumounne_ est probablement le plus courant dans mon coin.

Comment: @personne Sa doit dépendre alors, oui. Mes grand-parents viennent de gaspé, et il ont des ancêtres acadien, donc peut-etre plus une expression qui vient de la alors :)

Comment: @Laure I didn't say "school", I said elementary school. I meant that for a 7-9 year old kid, if you say swear wordslike "*pute*" or "*connard*" you can get in trouble, with your teacher at shcool or with your parents if you're at home. I should have said it differently to be more specific. Of course students in *lycée* won't get in trouble for saying "*merde*". But I doubt a kid will get a remark from teachers or parents if he say "*femelette*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I had perfectly  understood we were both talking about elementary school children. Even 50 years ago no teacher in the south of France would have raised an eyebrow for *putain*, let alone parents, everyone uses it. *Merde* can be heard almost everywhere inside as well as outside the classroom (even said by teachers), sometimes with an apology as an afterthought, but no one gets punished for saying it.

Comment: [Dans le midi de la France, par exemple, ponctuer ses phrases de : « Putain ! Con ! » est très fréquent alors qu’en région parisienne on dira « merde » plus facilement.](https://www.filsantejeunes.com/les-gros-mots-7026).... If teachers or parents don't tell their kids off for saying *femelette*, considering it is a personal and sexist insult, then they are not doing their jobs as educators, and for a teacher it is a professional mistake.

Comment: Je confirme pour ma part l’utilisation de feluette dans ma partie du Québec (pas acadienne du tout).

Answer (score 11):

*Femmelette* is offensive because it's an insult in two parts. The *-lette* suffix is a diminutive, saying that the person is less than a *femme*. And it builds on *femme* (i.e. “woman”), saying that the person is inferior for being a woman.

If *femmelette* was the feminine version of **hommelet*, it would merely be an insult. But *hommelet* doesn't exist. Using *femmelette* is intrinsically sexist.

(My perspective is from France. Some dialects may use the word more or less, but the offensiveness is cross-dialectal.)

Comment: I don't want to raise any controversy here: this answer is right. But a woman that looks or behave like a man is sometimes referred to as a “fomme” (or perhaps “fhomme”?) in Quebec. This hasn't made it to any dictionary I know, it is uncommon even in Quebec, but would it surf a wave at some point in the future, I believe it could be a legitimate masculine version of “femmelette”, even though it's pointing to a different sexist stereotype (roughness of men instead of weakness of women).

Comment: @Montéedelait Huh. I've never heard or read that word, it hasn't made its way to France. Is it even “un fhomme” or “une fhomme”? The spelling *fhomme* is somewhat transparent (at least if you don't get sidetrack thinking the F is a typo) but I'm not sure I'd have understood if I'd heard it.

Comment: Peut-être [œ̃n fɔm] serait-il approprié? :~) Dans mon monde on dit «une fhomme»...

Comment: It is definitely sexist in the sense that it infers acting like a (weak) woman is a bad thing, to be ashamed of, but interpreting it as "a woman being weak for **being a woman**" is an extra step. In my opinion there is no meaning of causality in any of the "-lette" words. (noisette, maisonette, pincette, etc)

Comment: _Hommasse_ is an adjective, not a noun, yet it is offensive and used to described a woman who acts or looks like a man. And _hommelet_ would sound like either _homme laid_ or _omelette_ !

Comment: @Montéedelait I was curious about it and [*fomme*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fomme) and [*hemme*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hemme) can be found in the wiktionnaire, no definitions. Urban dictionary has [*fomme*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fomme) but the definition given doesn't match yours. Wiktionnaire gives a quotation form a Quebec women's studies journal. And the terms were apparently used by the French writer Françoise Dorin in 2007, so they must be known in some circles this side of the Pond.

Comment: @Laure Good find. So the word would exist in both genders in some circles, and as a noun to designate some mild sort of hermaphrodicity. Maybe the (pejorative) acception of the people I know is not to be the final one, who knows?

Comment: @Laure [Une autre définition](https://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/une-fomme.html) informelle, plus près de celle que j’ai fournie, datant de 2006.

Comment: @Montéedelait Les mots en train de se créer et de se chercher, c'est intéressant. C'est visiblement parti du Québec, et c'est aussi intéressant de voir que le français n'est pas un phénomène hexagonal et peut-être est-il plus vivant au Québec qu'en France !

Comment: @Laure Pas un phénomène STRICTEMENT hexagonal. Je crois qu'il faut encore considérer la France comme une région particulièrement effervescente de la Francophonie...

Comment: Oui, tout à fait, bien sûr. Mais les Français sont souvent très coincés sur la langue... peur du néologisme et de la création langagière.

Comment: "ette" is just a diminutive, which is not intrinsically insulting, it can even be affectionate.  But in the context of an insult it does add another layer of insult instead.  Especially in the context of sexist insults.