# « Parler comme en cul de poule » : sens ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, québec, france

C'est dans le texte suivant de [user λyoye d'oncques](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=59355897#59355897) que se trouve cette expression crue et bizarre, « parler comme en cul de poule ».

> Je veux dire, on n'est pas dans un salon des Lumières, une clinique de littérature créative ou un studio de proofreading pour parler comme en cul de poule ici. Il s'agit d'une site sur la langue française.

Le terme « cul de poule », qui est reconnu comme n'étant que familier au Wiktionnaire (bien qu'à mon avis dans les emplois figuratifs au moins c'est grossier), est cependant bien connu dans les expressions « bouche en cul de poule » et « faire le cul de poule ».

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_le_cul_de_poule))
> **faire le cul de poule**
>
> Locution verbale
>
> faire le cul de poule
> (Familier) Faire une sorte de moue, en avançant et pressant les lèvres.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cul))  B.− [P. anal. de forme]
> − **Bouche en cul(-)de(-)poule** v. cul(-)de(-)poule.

Ces analogies de forme ne mènent pas précisément à une définition.

S'agit-il de « parler en faisant le cul de poule », ce qui aurait vraisemblablement le sens figuré de parler en faisant figurativement la moue en question à une grande partie de ce qui est dit ou proposé, c'est à dire en prononçant des jugements défavorables, ou s'agirait-il d'autre chose comme simplement « douter de tout » ?

Existe-t-il une telle expression ?   Quelle est l'expression exacte, « parler comme en cul de poule »,  « parler en cul de poule » ou « parler en faisant le cul de poule » ?

Il existe bien une définition québécoise de « parler en cul de poule » mais ce n'est toujours pas « parler comme en cul de poule », et le sens ne semble pas convenir (un parler, en comparaison, précieux ?), mais sait-on jamais.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/parler-en-cul-de-poule))
>
> **parler en cul de poule** Locution verbale \paʁ.le ɑ̃ ky də pul
> (Québec) (Péjoratif) (Figuré) Emprunter, imiter l'accent parisien ou se forcer à n'avoir aucun accent.
> •    R'garde le qui parle en cul de poule! On le sait ben! Monsieur est pas d'la même classe que nous autres.
> •  Depuis qu'elle est revenue de France, elle parle en cul de poule.

(Personnellement, je trouve cette question de décider de ce qui est vraiment dit assez énigmatique.)

Comment: C'est une façon ‘précieuse’ de choisir ses mots et de moduler le ton, le timbre et le rythme de son élocution. Le dit avec ***la bouche** en cul-de-poule* dénote une intention de se démarquer du langage commun.

Comment: @Personne Les réponses ne devraient pas être faites dans les commentaires, et des références sont toujours souhaitables.

Comment: Les réponses se trouvent sur mon profile https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile

Comment: @Personne Pourquoi ne serait-ce pas, au lieu d'une intention, une façon naturelle de parler, tout bonnement parce que  c'est celle du  milieu dans lequel on a évolué  ? La définition du Québec montre que la façon naturelle de parler du Parisien peut être appelée « en cul de poule », au Québec tout au moins.

Comment: @LPH Il semble que ton but est de contester le sens de l'expression ou plutôt remettre en cause son utilisation à ton sujet plutôt que de chercher à le comprendre, puisque tout le monde comprend parfaitement la signification de *parler comme en cul de poule*, toi inclus.

Comment: @jlliagre Mon but est clairement expliqué dans la question, pour qui veut bien lire :  1/ Savoir si l'expression est correcte parce qu'on ne la trouve pas, il n'y a pas « comme » dans celles qu'on trouve. Ensuite , 2/,  c'est de savoir ce qu'elle signifie ; est-ce que c'est parler d'une certaine façon  (pointu ou avec un accent snob ou comme un Parisien ou ce qu'on voudra de ce genre-là) ou bien est-ce que c'est faire la moue (figurativement) sur ce que l'on propose, c'est à dire le rejeter comme n'étant pas bon (et ça, ce n'est que mon hypothèse) ? Ça n'est vraiment pas évident, pas du tout !

Answer (score 1):

1. Oui, l'expression est valide. Rien n'interdit d'insérer ici l'adverbe ***comme*** pour signifier « de la même manière que ».

   > TLFi [Comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme)
   > **II.−** Morphème de comparaison. Dans ces emplois comme exprime une idée de similitude, l'écart avec l'idée d'identité pouvant être plus ou moins réduit selon le contexte.

   On pourrait aussi dire :

   Il parle avec les mains → Il parle comme avec les mains.
   Il parle en bégayant → Il parle comme en bégayant.

   En France au moins, on utilise aussi *genre* avec le même sens:

   Il parle genre avec les mains.
   Il parle genre en bégayant.
2. La signification est celle que tu as trouvée : parler de manière exagérément et ridiculement affectée. *En cul de poule* est évidemment lié à l'expression *[bouche en cul de poule](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouche_en_cul_de_poule)*.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais trouvé ce principe qui dirait que « comme » ne change rien dans certaines constructions. Ensuite qu'est-ce que c'est que ce « en » ?  On doit comprendre « comme **dedans** un cul de poule » ? Sans « en » peut-être, mais c'est toujours du non-sens. Ce n'est pas possible, c'est idiot. Cette explication est très douteuse. En plus on ne trouve pas « [parle comme avec les mains](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parle+comme+avec+les+mains&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) », et ça se comprend puisque ça ne sert strictement à rien.

Comment: *Parler comme avec la bouche en cul de poule*. Qu'est-ce que tu ne comprends pas ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'ellipse évidente de « avec la bouche », c'est trop ; c'est encore une addition qui n'a rien à voir dans cette expression.

Comment: Bien sûr qu'il s'agit de la bouche, c'est bien avec elle qu'on parle, non?

Comment: C'est « comme en », pas «comme avec la bouche en ». D'abord, où est -ce que cette expression idiomatique se trouve dans les références ? Il y a aussi le fait que dans les endroits cités on ne parle pas d'une manière affectée ; il n'y a que de rares cas ; le parler est tout à fait normal (par exemple, [un salon littéraire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzKF6cQlfRo)).

Comment: 1. Ellipse, procédé stylistique courant. 2. Dans ta question, tu cites Wikipedia. 3. Hors-sujet. C'est une opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144889/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lph).

Answer (score 1):

C'est une façon ‘précieuse’ de choisir ses mots et de moduler le ton, le timbre et le rythme de son élocution. Le dit avec ***la bouche** en cul-de-poule* dénote une intention de se démarquer du langage commun. ([Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/parler-comme-en-cul-de-poule-sens#comment110218_52680))

Answer (score 1):

L'expression peut aussi désigner par analogie le prétentieux ou *snob* ([Laparlure.com](https://www.laparlure.com/terme/parler-en-trou-du-cul-de-poule-trou-dcul-dpoule/)) et on trouve ce genre de commentaire chez le [pamphlétaire québécois](https://www.tlfq.org/fonds/citation/244777). La phrase réussit bien à évoquer l'expression il me semble et l'ellipse ou l'ajout d'un élément ([*comme*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52686)) à *en [cul de poule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cul-de-poule)*, où *en* introduit la forme, ne saurait l'anéantir et d'ailleurs d'aucuns auront spontanément compris son sens et l'auront acceptée (un peu comme avec*elle aime le lycée*, finalement), en plus du contexte qui aide (le salon des Lumières, la clinique spécialisée etc.). La définition trouvée sur *Wiktionnaire* évoque l'hypercorrection, la classe supérieure, le modèle inusité, pouvant facilement être associés à ce même contexte...

Et la référence à la [vocation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) du site qui suit (« ...à la langue française. Il s'adresse aux linguistes, aux enseignants, aux étudiants, et à toute personne qui s'intéresse de près à la langue française (y compris ses variations régionales ou dialectales). ») oppose d'autre part l'ouverture à la prescription, du garde champêtre ou autrement, et à la réduction, ajoutant à ce que précède.

L'auteur Réjean Ducharme réussit à marier avec esprit la forme (...de la bouche) et le fond dans cet [extrait](https://www.tlfq.org/fonds/citation/263992) de *L'hiver de force* :

> Toujours est-il que tout à coup ils se sont jetés de tous leurs becs
> (rien n'est plus pointu que des bouches en cul de poule) sur Fernand
> Gignac, un crooner que les petites Québécoises osent adorer uniquement
> parce qu'elles le trouvent gentil. C'est que la radio s'était mise à
> jouer son plus récent succès, un duo tendre.

Comment: Alors on peut dire par exemple «une bouche en pot à pisser » ? Ça ne serait pas offensant, pas empreint de mépris fasciste, d'après vous ?

Comment: Peu importe qui et où, c'est la chose, en elle-même, qui reste ce qu'elle est qui que ce soit qui s'en serve. Ça n'a rien à voir avec moi, et le mépris, quoique personnellement je l'appellerais pas « fasciste »—mais c'est un terme qui vous est cher—, je ne le vois que dans ces deux analogies ; en fait, même si je les considère ingénieuses—([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poule), « dans lesquelles l'anal. de forme est évidente) »), je les trouve indésirables, de la même manière que tout le monde avait trouvé indésirable le terme « femmelette », dans lequel je ne vois  (1/2)

Comment: pas de mépris puisqqu'il ne veut dire vraiment pas autre chose que « femme de très petite stature », avec tout ce que ça implique. Néanmoins, user Gilles et  plusieurs autres considéraient ce terme [offensant](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39478/17649) vu les connotations indéniables d'infériorité qui s'en dégagent (il faut bien pourtant un critère d'infériorité) ; cependant, dans ces deux termes on a en plus d'une idée d'infériorité des associations à des choses répugnantes. Je demande donc si ce « mariage avec esprit » ne serait pas plutôt questionnable. (2/2)

Comment: Alors on peut, selon vous ; c'est la réponse, il faut croire.

Comment: @LPH Rien n'empêche de dire quoi que ce soit. La « une bouche en pot à pisser » est inusité mais on comprend généralement la forme. Est-ce qu'on comprend la même chose que la bouche en cul de poule, je ne crois pas.